# How to test Google App Engine app locally with Hot Reloading and other supported libraries?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

In the past, we can test GAE apps with `dev_appserver.py [/path/to/my-project]`. This was very useful because it provided helpful error messages in the terminal.

With the advent of `gcloud` SDK, it is [suggested](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/quickstart#run_hello_world_on_your_local_machine) that we set up a `virtualenv` and test apps locally by running `python main.py`. Is this the recommended way for large apps too? Or is this just a *quick-start way* to demonstrate how to run App Engine locally?

What is the suggested local environment for building production-ready GAE apps?

Answer (score 1):

The SDK was previously providing a local dev_appserver since the App Engine Standard [1st generation environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/runtimes) was integrating built-in APIs (Datastore, Memcache, etc...) that needed to be emulated locally to properly run/test your application.

The 2nd generation now deprecated these built-in APIs and rely on Cloud Client Libraries (more info on the runtime differences [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences)). This means that you don't need anymore an emulated environment for your local testing. Your application, either large or small, should be able to run indifferently locally and when deployed.